# Delete all characters before and after quotation marks

Tags: csv, replace

I have a CSV file, which has two columns and 4500 rows. In one column, I have several phrases that are surrounded in quotation marks. I need to delete all the text that comes before and after the quotations marks.

For example:

```
How would you say "Hello, my Friend" when speaking outside?
should become "Hello, my Friend"
```

I also have several rows that have the word NULL in the second column. I need these rows deleted in full.

What's the best way of doing something like this? I have been looking at regular expressions, but I'm not sure if they are flexible enough to do what I want to do, or how you would use them on a CSV file (I need the table structure to remain).

EDIT:
1) At the moment I am just using Apple Numbers, but I know that wont don't it, so I am happy to any suggestions. It must support Kanji characters.

2) I have removed all the NULL rows, so that is no longer needed (I simply added a column of numbers, sorted the table so all the NULLs were together, deleted them and the sorted back by the column of numbers).

Comment: This is easy string parsing for most languages. What tools are you intending to use? You might find Excel handy.

Comment: @shawnt00. At the moment I am just using Apple Numbers, but I know that wont don't it, so I am happy to any suggestions. It must support Kanji characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find a text editor that supports regular expression search and replace.

Something like this would match `,NULL` in the second column: `^.*,NULL.*$`. Replace it with "DELETEMEDELETEME" to mark the line, or as an empty string or find a way to have it match on `\n' or '\r' to catch the line break and remove the entire line completely.

Stripping out parts of the quoted string might work like this:

`^(.*,){n}(.*)(\".\")(.*)(,.*)$` replaced with `\1\3\5` where n is the number of columns preceding the one you want to edit. Repeat `(.*,)` if that's not available. It will depend on the regex flavor of your tool.

Comment: Extra Info for anyone trying this: I used the Sublime Texteditor to apply the Regex (Press CMD + OPT +F to bring up the "Find Bar", then select the first icon for "Regular Expressions"). Removing quotes marks was tricky, so I did a find and replace to swap them with § symbols. I then applied the following Regex commands`^[^§]*§` & `\§.*$`. The first one removes all text before the symbol. The second one removes all text after the symbol. If a line doesn't contain a symbol, it will be removed completely. I then did a find and replace to return the § symbols back to quote marks.